# Como codar esse layout?

Tags: html, css

1 - Como dar este aspecto da "div" estar em um plano mais alto que o body, gerando a sombra?
2 - Neste caso, a section tem uma certa transparência e a div é sólida?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da pra fazer via css, mas esses tipos de layout a galera faz com imagem recortada mesmo.

Comment: Beleza, mas caso eu escolha com css, o modo que citei está correto para chegar a este resultado?

Comment: Bem vinda ao StackOverflow em Português, talvez queira fazer uma **Tour**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour ou dar uma olhada na **Central de Ajuda**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help e verificar como efetuar perguntas de uma forma que sejam respondidas rapidamente, tente informar o que você já tentou e poste o seu código, dificilmente alguém fará o trabalho por você.

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode ser feito com um efeito de sombreamento bem simples:

```css
.teste1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.teste2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
```

```html
<div class="teste1">
  <div class="teste2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Repare que as duas div´s tem a mesma cor, a direfença é que em uma apliquei um leve sombreamento, logo o nível de profundidade fica a seu critério

[Box shadow css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/)

Answer (score 1):

basicamente você precisa brincar com o `background-color`, um `rgba(r, g, b, 0.5)` deve resolver, ja o efeito de revelo, você consegue com o `box-shadow`

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(0,150,136);
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(238,238,238);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px silver;
}

#subheader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgb(224,224,224);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 120px);
  background-color: rgba(224,224,224,0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

#box {
  background-color: rgb(224,224,224);
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="subheader"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```